# Реализация в текстовом поле математических выражений

Tags: qt, gui

> Возможно ли реализовать в Qplaintextedit или в Qtextedit ввод
>   математических формул (корни, дроби,интегралы) и отображение как в
>   word или как в графических калькуляторов? Если возможно, какие
>   библиотеки и функции подключать

Была идея использовать Qplaintextedit и спускать и поднимать строку в зависимости от формулы, есть ли такие функции?

Добавление символов кодировки не будет отображать как нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Весьма маловероятно. Можно поискать интеграцию LaTex в Qt, но это будет картинками. Ввод формул в текстовые поля это не такая простая задача.

Comment: Попробуйте сюда посмотреть, может быть пригодится? :) http://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1126142.html

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Данный метод отображает в картинку а затем форму. Для текстового ввода, который можно изменять не годится

Comment: @ixSci в каком направлении двигаться? можно ли поставить текстовое поле?

Comment: Я думаю, что в этом направлении не нужно двигаться. Это очень сложная задача. Лично мне вообще не известны редакторы, которые создают формулы «на лету», за исключением Word. А его разрабатывают тысячи людей с полной поддержкой MS. Остальные редакторы полагаются на LaTex, с последующем рендером в картинки, потому что это куда проще, да и более гибко, я полагаю. LaTex это сдандарт де факто для ввода формул.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю отображение математических символов можно организовать с  html и mathml, который можно отображать
в qtextbrowser . Чтобы можно было печатать нужно будет ,либо 
отлавливать  нажатие клавиши qtextbrowser'ом  ,либо **добавлять
html теги в qtextedit.**
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461205/how-to-have-subscript-and-superscript-in-pyqt-textedit